# Which jQuery packages are included in Wordpress 3.1.2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I haven't found a document, except [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) one, that says which jQuery packages are included by wordpress. Thus, I don't know if I should add jQuery to my header.php or not.

The link above, doesn't state the version of the libraries included nor the wordpress version that this applies to.

Should I load jQuery UI manually?

Answer (score 3):

On the front end (i.e. in a Theme) don't enqueue jQuery or jQuery UI unless you actually need to *use* either of them. On the back end (i.e. in the Admin area), both will already be enqueued, since core uses them.

Whatever the case, if you use a core-bundled script, you should *always use the version bundled with core*, since core, Themes, and Plugins will all expect the core-bundled version to be registered.

That said, as of WordPress 3.2.1, not *all* jQuery UI plugins are included in core, so if you need to use a plugin that is not in the list on the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) page, you'll need to bundle and register that plugin yourself.

As of WordPress 3.3, **all jQuery UI plugins** will be bundled/registered in core, and will thus be available to be enqueued.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress comes pre-loaded with jQuery, jQuery UI, Scriptaculous and a lot of other helpful JavaScript libraries. You can see all of them in the `wp-includes/js` folder of your WP installation. All you have to do is `wp_enqueue_script` them to use in your themes / plugins.